# CSS Transitions max-width and max-height

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I have an `object` inside a `div` container. The object has the `max-width (600px)` and `max-height (400px)` properties set. When I hover the object, the properties are set to `none` so the object's `width` and `height` can be rendered properly. However when moving the mouse out of the `object` it immediatly changes it's `width` and `height` to the `max-width (600px)` and `max-height (400px)` values and after one second it falls back to it's original `width` and `height` values.

So how can I do the transitions to make the `object` change it's `width` and `height` smoothly, both, when hovering over it and when mousing out.

HTML:

```
<html>
<!-- Blah blah some head tags here. -->
<body>
  <div id="c_a">
    <object data="https://www.google.ro/images/srpr/logo11w.png" type="image/png"></object>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
  font-size: larger;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#c_a object{
  transition: width 1s linear .5s, height 1s linear .5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s linear .5s, height 1s linear .5s;
  -o-transition: width 1s linear .5s, height 1s linear .5s;
  -moz-transition: width 1s linear .5s, height 1s linear .5s;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
#c_a object:hover{
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  max-width: none;
  max-height: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv4y4/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have width specified on the parent element.

You have percent widths on your `object` as *100%*. *100%* of what? It is the *100%* percent of the parent element's width, your `div` in this case. If the parent element doesn't have the width specified, then you end up with such problem(s).

***Solution***: Specify a width on your wrapper `div`.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Pv4y4/4/***

*CSS*:

```
div#c_a { width: 200px; } /* specify width on parent here */

#c_a object {
    -webkit-transition: width 1s linear .5s, height 1s linear .5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
#c_a object:hover {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
}
```

***Note***: Ideally you would also specify `height` on the parent.

---

### Update:

As long as the specified width on the parent `div` is within the rules of `max-width` it will work fine. However, once the initial width breaches or nears the `max-width` rule, then the transition will take it beyond the `max-width` and then will snap back to the original.

***Problem***: Specifying the transition separately on `width` and `height` will not work as it tries to transition on those properties only and thus `max-`es are ignored. Hence the jumping effect.

***Solution***: First, Do not specify the `max-`es as `none`. Because you are increasing the image size by 200%, specify these also as 200%. Second, specify transition as-is without specific properties. This makes all the relevant properties get transitioned and will help mitigate the problem to some extent.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Pv4y4/9/***

*CSS*:

```
html, body { width: 100%; }
div#c_a { width: 60%; }
#c_a object {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    ...
}
#c_a object:hover {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    max-width: 200%;
    max-height: 200%;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if I only want to use percentanges? Look up, I've edited the post.

Comment: That's fine. But you haven't still specified any width/height on your parent `div`. You *will* have to do that.

Comment: Hmmm... in this case when the `max-width` is breached, then it snaps back. Yes. Give me some time..

Comment: @user3661754: There. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change `max-width`/`max-height` smoothly, you must specify the `max-*` in the minimized state and set width/height to `auto`:

```
#c_a object{ {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 1ms;
    transition: position 1s, left 1s, top 1s, width 1s, height 1s, max-width 1s, max-height 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#c_a object:hover {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can do like this

```
transition: max-width 1s linear .5s;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hvosanzL/